# Ajax ou Jquery: transição entre páginas externas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Oi, pessoal!

Estou tendo um problemão com meu site, mas não consegui resolver de forma alguma usando o SO em inglês, muito menos os tutoriais de outros sites.

Minha página inicial tem dois botões que levam para as páginas posteriores (pag1 e pag2, por exemplo). Quando eu clico em um dos botões, eu preciso que haja uma transição estilo slider para mudar as páginas. Não posso fazer isso criando div's nem iFrames pois preciso que o URL mude e a responsividade do site seja mantida. Já testei esses dois métodos sem sucesso.

Alguém aqui pode me ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Leia [ask] para saber como fazer uma boa pergunta. Clique em [edit] e adicione seu código. Recomendo a leitura  [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Obrigado, Diego! Meu código não tem utilidade nesse caso, já que nenhum dos métodos que eu utilizei foram válidos. Eu postei a dúvida porque preciso começar do zero. Obrigado novamente pelo aviso!

Comment: Cara, quando você abre outra URL você faz uma requisição, se estiver abrindo outra pagina, crei oque nao tem como fazer esse efeito que você quer